# Dynamical reserve of Lock-in amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ac, power-electronics

I am trying to understand how my lock-in Stanford RS830 works and therefore I am going trhough the manual. There is however one thing I cannot understand: whyever should I use a minimum dynamical range? For instance, if I set sensitivity to 50uV, I could set dynamical range 37dB, eventhough the instrument can work with a dynamical reserve of 100dB

Comment: Sorry, never worked with that particular device. Got a datasheet and/or manual link for us?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is SR830 (not RS830). Manual: https://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/pdfs/manuals/SR830m.pdf